# Find the linear function $f$ whose composition $f\circ f\circ f\circ\dots$ ($6$ times) is equal to $2x-1$ for all $x$

Tags: functions

I am not able to start the solution, so can get a hint for this one?

Thanks

Comment: Composing $x\mapsto ax+b$ $n$ times will surely give $x\mapsto a^nx+\text{something}$.

Comment: We could equivalently look for a $6$th root of the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{2&-1\\0&1}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)=ax+b$ then $f(f(...(f(x)))))=a^{6}x+b(1+a+a^{2}+a^{3}+a^{4}+a^{5})$. Equate this to $2x-1$ and compare coefficients to find the values of $a$ and $b$.